# shell script to print rows if there is a value in column 2

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, columns

```
1 2 3 4
3 1 4 2
1 4 3 2
4 2 1 3
```

How can I print all rows, on which there is a ***2*** in the second column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `awk` (or its cousin `gawk`):

```
gawk '$2==2 {print $0}' inputfile
```

In `awk` columns are indicated by a `$`, with `$1` the first column, `$2` the second, etc. The whole line is given by `$0`. So this example reads: if column 2 is equal to 2, print the whole line.

Edit: as devnull said below:

```
gawk '$2==2' inputfile
```

is enough. To print the lines with 2 in the second column and 4 in the last use `$NF`, which stands for the Number of Fields (i.e. the last column):

```
gawk '$2==2 && $NF==4'  inputfile
```

Comment: `{print $0}` is redundant here.  You could simply say `awk '{$2==2}' inputfile`.

Comment: @devnull, ITYM `awk '$2==2'` or `awk '$2=="2"'` if you want string comparison (not consider `02` or `2.0` as the same as `2`). `gawk` is more the grand-daughter of `awk` than its cousin ;-)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Right, it seems that the OP would want to quote `2`.

Comment: is it possible to specify and ,if i want to print row with 2 in second column and 4 in last column.

Comment: @KevinParker Say `awk '$2=="2" && $NF=="4"' inputfile`

Comment: or `awk '$2 ~ /2/ && $NF ~ /'TEST'/ {print }'` filename

Comment: @val0x00ff no, that will also print `foobar2barfoo`, `~//` is a match operator and will be true for substrings. Also, you can't have nested `'`, you'd have to use `"`.